# How do I fix this error? dkms.conf: Error! No 'BUILT_MODULE_NAME' directive specified for record #0 Error! Bad conf file

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, kernel, dkms

I am using Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS

Does anyone know how to fix this dkms.conf error?

```
dkms.conf: Error! No 'BUILT_MODULE_NAME' directive specified for record #0.
Error! Bad conf file.
File: 
does not represent a valid dkms.conf file.
Setting up linux-headers-generic (3.13.0.35.42) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.19-0ubuntu6.3) ...

$ dkms status

bbswitch, 0.7, 3.13.0-34-generic, x86_64: installed
bbswitch, 0.7, 3.13.0-35-generic, x86_64: installed
nvidia-331-updates, 331.38, 3.13.0-34-generic, x86_64: installeddkms.conf: Error! No       'BUILT_MODULE_NAME' directive specified for record #0.
Error! Bad conf file.
File: 
does not represent a valid dkms.conf file.

nvidia-331-updates, 331.38, 3.13.0-35-generic, x86_64: installed

$ ls -R /var/lib/dkms


/var/lib/dkms:
bbswitch  dkms_dbversion  nvidia-331-updates  xpad

/var/lib/dkms/bbswitch:
0.7  kernel-3.13.0-34-generic-x86_64  kernel-3.13.0-35-generic-x86_64

/var/lib/dkms/bbswitch/0.7:
3.13.0-34-generic  3.13.0-35-generic  build  source

/var/lib/dkms/bbswitch/0.7/3.13.0-34-generic:
x86_64

/var/lib/dkms/bbswitch/0.7/3.13.0-34-generic/x86_64:
log  module

/var/lib/dkms/bbswitch/0.7/3.13.0-34-generic/x86_64/log:
make.log

/var/lib/dkms/bbswitch/0.7/3.13.0-34-generic/x86_64/module:
bbswitch.ko

/var/lib/dkms/bbswitch/0.7/3.13.0-35-generic:
x86_64

/var/lib/dkms/bbswitch/0.7/3.13.0-35-generic/x86_64:
log  module

/var/lib/dkms/bbswitch/0.7/3.13.0-35-generic/x86_64/log:
make.log

/var/lib/dkms/bbswitch/0.7/3.13.0-35-generic/x86_64/module:
bbswitch.ko

/var/lib/dkms/bbswitch/0.7/build:
bbswitch.c  dkms.conf  Makefile

/var/lib/dkms/nvidia-331-updates:
331.38  kernel-3.13.0-34-generic-x86_64  kernel-3.13.0-35-generic-x86_64

/var/lib/dkms/nvidia-331-updates/331.38:
3.13.0-34-generic  3.13.0-35-generic  build  source

/var/lib/dkms/nvidia-331-updates/331.38/3.13.0-34-generic:
x86_64

/var/lib/dkms/nvidia-331-updates/331.38/3.13.0-34-generic/x86_64:
log  module

/var/lib/dkms/nvidia-331-updates/331.38/3.13.0-34-generic/x86_64/log:
make.log

/var/lib/dkms/nvidia-331-updates/331.38/3.13.0-34-generic/x86_64/module:
nvidia_331_updates.ko

/var/lib/dkms/nvidia-331-updates/331.38/3.13.0-35-generic:
x86_64

/var/lib/dkms/nvidia-331-updates/331.38/3.13.0-35-generic/x86_64:
log  module

/var/lib/dkms/nvidia-331-updates/331.38/3.13.0-35-generic/x86_64/log:
make.log

/var/lib/dkms/nvidia-331-updates/331.38/3.13.0-35-generic/x86_64/module:
nvidia_331_updates.ko

/var/lib/dkms/nvidia-331-updates/331.38/build:
conftest.sh          g_nvreadme.h   nv-chrdev.c  nv-frontend.c  nv.h                      nv-memdbg.h   nv-p2p.c     nv-reg.h            nv-vm.c         os-registry.c  rmretval.h
conftest.sh.orig     Makefile       nv.c.orig    nv-frontend.h  nv-i2c.c                  nv-mempool.c  nv-p2p.h     nvtypes.h           nv-vtophys.c    os-smp.c       xapi-sdk.h
cpuopsys.h           Makefile.orig  nv-cray.c    nv_gpu_ops.h   nvidia-modules-common.mk  nv-misc.h     nv-pat.c     nv-usermap.c        os-interface.c  os-usermap.c
dkms.conf            nv-acpi.c      nv-drm.c     nvgputypes.h   nv-kernel.o               nv-mlock.c    nv-procfs.c  nv_uvm_interface.c  os-interface.h  patches
gcc-version-check.c  nv.c           nverror.h    nv-gvi.c       nv-linux.h                nv-mmap.c     nv-proto.h   nv_uvm_interface.h  os-pci.c        rmil.h

/var/lib/dkms/nvidia-331-updates/331.38/build/patches:
allow_sublevel_greater_than_5.patch  buildfix_kernel_3.11.patch  buildfix_kernel_3.6.patch                 register-VT-switch-requirements.patch
buildfix_kernel_3.0.patch            buildfix_kernel_3.13.patch  buildfix_kernel_3.8.patch                 replace-VM_RESERVED-with-VM_DONTEXPAND-and-VM_DONTDU.patch
buildfix_kernel_3.10.patch           buildfix_kernel_3.14.patch  make-use-of-the-new-uapi-framework.patch

/var/lib/dkms/xpad:
0.1  kernel-3.13.0-34-generic-x86_64

/var/lib/dkms/xpad/0.1:
3.13.0-34-generic  build  source

/var/lib/dkms/xpad/0.1/3.13.0-34-generic:
x86_64

/var/lib/dkms/xpad/0.1/3.13.0-34-generic/x86_64:
log  module

/var/lib/dkms/xpad/0.1/3.13.0-34-generic/x86_64/log:
make.log

/var/lib/dkms/xpad/0.1/3.13.0-34-generic/x86_64/module:
xpad.ko

/var/lib/dkms/xpad/0.1/build:
dkms.conf  Makefile  xpad.c
```

Comment: Problem slightly solved from reading http://askubuntu.com/questions/227258/error-could-not-locate-dkms-conf-file?rq=1    I know that it is a problem with the SteamOS-xpad-dkms from https://launchpad.net/~mdeslaur/+archive/ubuntu/steamos

Answer (score 0):

The error message is about a file called dkms.conf.

Test this:

Search to files with that name:

```
sudo su
find dkms.conf
```

Verify that corresponds to nvidia.

Example:

/var/lib/dkms/nvidia/331.38/build/dkms.conf

```
cat /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/331.38/build/dkms.conf
 PACKAGE_NAME="nvidia"
 PACKAGE_VERSION="331.38"
 DEST_MODULE_LOCATION[0]="/updates"
 AUTOINSTALL="yes"
```

Purge the package

```
sudo su 
dpkg --purge nvidia-dkms
```

Comment: find dkms.conf        find: `dkms.conf': No such file or directory

Comment: cat /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/331.38/build/dkms.conf                    cat: /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/331.38/build/dkms.conf: No such file or directory

Comment: dpkg --purge nvidia-dkms                                      dpkg: warning: ignoring request to remove nvidia-dkms which isn't installed

Comment: /var/lib/dkms/nvidia-331-updates/331.38/build: ....  os-usermap.c ... ***dkms.conf***... nv-acpi.c Delete it