Laptop keyboard not working after suspend 22.04 Dell XPS 13 9370
Around 2024-04-12 my laptop keyboard stopped responding.
Only rebooting gets the keyboard working again.
Experimenting showed the keyboard stops working after suspend, quite reliably.
$ dmidecode
...
System Information
        Manufacturer: Dell Inc.
        Product Name: XPS 13 9370

The boot parameters recommended in other threads i8042.reset i8042.nomux=1
did not help.  (Was not exhaustive on this, in particular, didn't try dumbkbd)
What is causing the issue?

I found a similar issue for a different distribution, due to a kernel bug
https://lore.kernel.org/linux-input/20240126160724.13278-1-hdegoede@redhat.com/
5.15.0-105-generic and 5.15.0-102-generic present were affected.
Downgrading my kernel to 5.15.0-101-generic is a temporary fix, the keyboard works after suspend (following https://askubuntu.com/a/779292/166514):
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-5.15.0-101 linux-headers-5.15.0-101-generic linux-image-5.15.0-101-generic linux-modules-extra-5.15.0-101-generic
sudo apt-mark manual linux-headers-5.15.0-101 linux-headers-5.15.0-101-generic linux-image-5.15.0-101-generic linux-modules-extra-5.15.0-101-generic

I suppose the long term fix is to wait for the upstream fix to flow in.

Commit to track https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/683cd8259a9b883a51973511f860976db2550a6e
As of 2024-04-25 it's in
v6.9-rc5  v6.9-rc4 v6.9-rc3 v6.9-rc2 v6.9-rc1 v6.8 v6.8-rc7 v6.8-rc6 v6.8-rc5 v6.8-rc4 v6.8-rc3

I see an identical issue with Ubuntu 23.10, on upgrade from 6.5.0-26-generic to 6.5.0-27-generic. Seems like an upgrade to 24.04, with 6.8.0-31 should include the fix.

Upgrading to 24.04 & kernel 6.8 looks like the long term fix, but I haven't yet tried
https://git.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-kernel/ubuntu/+source/linux/+git/noble/log/?qt=grep&q=skip+ATKBD_CMD_SETLEDS

I have the same problem with 6.5.0-*-generic on my Dell XPS 13 9370. I rebooted with 6.5.0-1023-oem and the keyboard now works fine after sleep.

Not a supported kernel for Ubuntu 22.04.
