# Nvidia init module is not rebuilt when I update kernel

Tags: nvidia, kernel

After upgrading linux kernel, I have to reinstall nvidia-driver. Otherwise, the display will not use GPU.

Now I need to do the following manaully after the kernel is updated

```
sudo apt remove nvidia-driver-396
sudo apt autoremove
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-396
```

Here is the system info

```
➜  ~ cat /etc/lsb-release                                     
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=18.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=bionic
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS"
```

And the GPU card

```
➜  ~ nvidia-smi   
Wed Sep 12 09:19:56 2018       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 396.54                 Driver Version: 396.54                    |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 108...  Off  | 00000000:01:00.0  On |                  N/A |
| 44%   42C    P2    61W / 250W |    531MiB / 11175MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
```

`dkms` is already installed.

```
➜  R-Net git:(master) ✗ sudo apt install dkms         
[sudo] password for vimos: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
dkms is already the newest version (2.3-3ubuntu9.2).
dkms set to manually installed.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 51 not upgraded.
```

`dkms status` outputs some strange error

```
➜  coqa_rnet git:(master) ✗ dkms status     
anbox, 1, 4.15.0-33-generic, x86_64: installedError! Could not locate dkms.conf file.
File:  does not exist.

anbox, 1, 4.15.0-34-generic, x86_64: installed
```

Am I missing any configuration for the module?

Thank you!

Comment: What does `dkms status` return?  Could you add that to your question?  Thank you!

Comment: @Terrance I added `dkms status` output, I guess there might be configuration overwrite in my machine.

Comment: Ah, yep.  Try running `sudo apt install nvidia-dkms-396` and then run the `dkms status` after that.  If the driver appears, then you should be good to go after that.  However, I am not sure about the anbox error you see there.  You can try this answer for the missing `dkms.conf` file:  https://askubuntu.com/a/636913/231142

Comment: @Terrance The link you shared helped me! I removed anbox and `dkms status` no more complains. I will wait for  the next kernel update to see if nvidia is OK. Thank you!