# sudo apt upgrade/autoremove gives error about dkms Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: apt, kernel, updates, dkms

Tried updating my system today. The updates went through, but the following error persists when I use `sudo apt autoremove` or `sudo apt upgrade`

```
sudo apt autoremove
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
4 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up linux-headers-5.4.0-48-generic (5.4.0-48.52) ...
/etc/kernel/header_postinst.d/dkms:
 * dkms: running auto installation service for kernel 5.4.0-48-generic
Error! Could not locate dkms.conf file.
File: /var/lib/dkms/anbox-ashmem/1/source/dkms.conf does not exist.
   ...fail!
run-parts: /etc/kernel/header_postinst.d/dkms exited with return code 4
dpkg: error processing package linux-headers-5.4.0-48-generic (--configure):
 installed linux-headers-5.4.0-48-generic package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-headers-generic:
 linux-headers-generic depends on linux-headers-5.4.0-48-generic; however:
  Package linux-headers-5.4.0-48-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-headers-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up linux-image-5.4.0-48-generic (5.4.0-48.52) ...
No apport report written because the error message indicates it's a follow-up error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                            dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-generic:
 linux-generic depends on linux-headers-generic (= 5.4.0.48.51); however:
  Package linux-headers-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates it's a follow-up error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                            Processing triggers for linux-image-5.4.0-48-generic (5.4.0-48.52) ...
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms:
 * dkms: running auto installation service for kernel 5.4.0-48-generic
Error! Could not locate dkms.conf file.
File: /var/lib/dkms/anbox-ashmem/1/source/dkms.conf does not exist.
   ...fail!
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms exited with return code 4
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-5.4.0-48-generic (--configure):
 installed linux-image-5.4.0-48-generic package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports has already been reached
                                                                    Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-headers-5.4.0-48-generic
 linux-headers-generic
 linux-generic
 linux-image-5.4.0-48-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I am using a custom kernel

```
uname -r
5.8.9-050809-generic
```

I googled the first error that mentions `anbox-ashmem` and I saw some very complicated (for me) discussions, hence I decided to post here to avoid breaking my system. I can restart and use everything normally at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

`sudo dpkg-reconfigure [package]` seems to be a popular fix for this, however it doesn't always work.

Solution from and possible duplicate of: [`Error! Could not locate dkms.conf file`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/227258/error-could-not-locate-dkms-conf-file)

Comment: I am not sure what package I need to reconfigure. I ran one of the commands from the thread you have linked, namely `for i in /var/lib/dkms/*/[^k]*/source; do [ -e "$i" ] || echo "$i";done`, which supposedly identifies the offending modules. It returned `/var/lib/dkms/anbox-ashmem/1/source` and `/var/lib/dkms/anbox-binder/1/source`, but I don't know what to do with these.

Comment: Remove and reinstall maybe? Not really sure how critical anbox is to the OS nor what it really does.